# How can I make a Label Provider using JSF-1.2?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I want to automatically set the labels attributes for the UIInput components in my pages, to the HtmlOutputLabel components I already put, like the PrimeFaces developer did: http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/label-provider-for-jsf-input-components/
Only he did it using System Events, a feature available only in JSF-2.0, and my application is in JSF 1.2.

Is it possible to do it using JSF-1.2, with maybe a Phase Listener?
What would be the drawbacks?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** This is what my attempt with a Phase Listener looks until now:

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("REGISTERING Label Provider");
    FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
    List<UIComponent> components = context.getViewRoot().getChildren();
    for (UIComponent uiComponent : components) {
        if (uiComponent instanceof HtmlOutputLabel) {
            HtmlOutputLabel outputLabel = (HtmlOutputLabel) uiComponent;
            System.out.println("CONFIGURING LABEL: " + outputLabel.getId());
            UIComponent target = outputLabel.findComponent(outputLabel
                    .getFor());
            if (target != null) {
                target.getAttributes().put("label", outputLabel.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    // Only listen during the render response phase.
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
}
```

When I access the view, it never prints the section "CONFIGURING LABEL". What would be the right test to verify if a uiComponent is a HtmlOutputLabel?
Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet, I'm trying to figure out how to get the HtmlOutputLabel in a PhaseListener to execute before the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase, and wondering if it is the right place to start...

Comment: There's no means of an APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase during a GET request in JSF 1.x. Do it before RENDER_RESPONSE.

Comment: wouldn't the validation messages using the labels have already been evaluated by then?

Comment: They're not used in a GET request at all. In a POST request it doesn't matter as the same view will just be reused (for which you've already set the labels in render response of the initial GET request).

Comment: Ah, understood! Thanks a lot, BalusC, you're always a great help! I'm having trouble to get the HtmlOutputLabels, I'm going to update the answer with my attempt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIViewRoot#getChildren()` only returns the **direct** children of the view root, not *all* children as you seem to expect. You need to iterate through the children of each child recursively as well.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    applyLabels(event.getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getChildren());
}

private static void applyLabels(List<UIComponent> components) {
    for (UIComponent component : components) {
        if (component instanceof HtmlOutputLabel) {
            // ...
        } else {
            applyLabels(component.getChildren()); // Reapply on its children.
        }
    }
}
```

Since JSF 2.0 the above is by the way convenienced with the [`UIComponent#visitTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree%28javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback%29) method which follows the visitor pattern so that you just have to make a single call.

Comment: Ouch, my mistake! I've fixed it now, works beautifully! Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: Hey, BalusC! I had to switch to before APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase, cause sometimes in a GET request the view root children list was coming empty. Do you have any idea why is that? Do you think doing it can be a problem doing it in this phase? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When exactly is "sometimes"? This will indeed happen on initial requests without pre render view events in JSF2, but not in JSF1 as far as I know. What JSF impl/version exactly are you using? Doing during apply request values should after all be good enough. You need this information during POST requests only anyway.

Comment: I wish I knew why it is "sometimes"... Yesterday it seemed to be working, today morning it wasn't. :/ Know something I can test? I'm using mojarra 1.2_15 (latest for 1.2 branch, as far as I know). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<h:outputText value="#{yourVO.tax}" />
```

Create a data transfer object (DTO) object in your action class and declare a string variable tax in the DTO, so that you can use it to set labels in your action class.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't see the real problem at all. This way you've still to define the value twice.

Comment: @Abhi_sr: I think you misunderstood my problem. I just don't want to repeat the labels in the h:outputLabel AND in the h:inputXXX associated.